# Trying to find the volume of a 3D torus shape that I made

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, 3d, parametric

After playing around with 3D parametric equations on my calculator (modifying the equations of a standard torus), I came across a shape that I like. The equations are:

$$x=(2+\sin t)\cos u$$
$$y=(2+\cos t)\sin u$$
$$z=\sin t\cos t$$

[image: The torus]

[image: The torus]

I would like to know how to find the volume and surface area of the shape. I have read a bit about surface integrals and Jacobian transformations to find the volume of a torus. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Torus.html

I went through an example of finding the volume of a normal (donut) torus with the jacobian transformation method i.e. $\frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(u,v,w)}$ and in the end the answer simplifies to $(c + a\cos v) a$.

I would very much appreciate if someone could help me with this and explain how all this remapping and multivariable changes work.

Comment: The last equation (for $z$) is surely what you wanted to write? It depends only on $t$.

Comment: yes, it only depends on t. I forgot to say that t and u go from 0 - 2π.

Comment: Then here is an upvote and a latex gift. BTW, the first ISN'T a torus equation, and none of your pictures contain a torus (if it is even possible to say, what the heck are shown on them).